# If ball bouncing looks like a modulated absolute value of a sine wave, then why not model bouncing this way?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, collision, projectile, models

If ball bouncing looks like a modulated abs of sine wave, then why not model bouncing this way?

[image]

Rather than this way:

https://se.mathworks.com/help/simulink/examples/simulation-of-a-bouncing-ball.html

Comment: It *looks* like a modulated sine wave, but it isn't! A graph of $x^3$ looks a lot like a graph of $x^5$, but there are important mathematical differences between them. In particular, the gradient of a sine wave is also sinusoidal (it's a cosine), but it's clear that here the velocity is not sinusoidal at all!

Comment: @gj255 What you mean it looks like but isn't? I mean, why can't it be replicated the modulation way?

Comment: mavavilj, in between the bounces, isn't the trajectory parabolic?

Comment: Paraphrasing George Box, "All models are wrong, some are useful" .  And  even *very* wrong models can be useful for specific use. But disaster can happen when we believe that the model *is* the true physics and fail to validate.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Can't such shape be made by modulating the sine wave with something?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Also it's possible that the shape would be that of sine wave, but the plotting "compresses" it.

Comment: mavavilj, think about it; if the shape in between bounces were the first half of a sine cycle,  the derivative would be the first half of a cosine cycle.  But the velocity plot (time derivative of position) isn't *remotely* sinusoidal, it's a *line*.  Also note that the time interval between bounces decreases with time and so, a modulated sinusoidal approximation to this must be of the form $|A(t)\cdot\sin(\omega(t)\,t)|$, i.e., both the modulation and amplitude change with time

Comment: I see that as I was typing my comment, an answer more or less covering my comment was posted.

Comment: @mavavilj, re, " Can't such shape be made by modulating the sine wave with something?"  Sure.  You could define a function, $f(x)$ such that $f(sin(x)) = a+bx+cx^2$ for some $a$, $b$, and $c$, and you could use that in your model; but what would be the point?  What would you _learn_ by doing it that way?

Comment: @jameslarge Modelling it that way seems much easier than the "physical" way described in the Matlab-link. When it comes to models, I prefer mathematical simplicity, if one can get away with it.

Comment: Something to keep in mind when designing a simulation.  Just writing the differential equations that approximate a systems behavior does *not* necessarily enforce other fundamental constraints, for example the conservation of energy. The result being that the simulation result is biased or unstable. This can be particularly amplified in nonlinear systems. One way to correct this issue is to use *symplectic* integration. Symplectic integration helps preserve energy and momentum conservation.

Comment: @mavavilj, OK, but keep in mind Einstein's admonishment to make your theory as simple as possible, but no simpler (i.e., don't make it so simple that it becomes wrong.)  A sinusoid may be simple, but it does not accurately describe the motion of a projectile (e.g.,  the flight of a ball between bounces).  My hypothetical $f(sin(x))$ "fixes" that, but only by adding significant complexity.  Maybe you don't think that quadratic equations are as simple as sinusoids, but they give the correct answer, _and_ they are simpler by far than my $f(sin(x))$ proposal.

Answer (score 12):

[Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x(pi-x)+and+(pi%2F2)%5E2sin(x)+from+0+to+pi) is a plot of a sine curve overtop a parabolic curve:

[image]

Close, but clearly different.  Also, if you wanted to show multiple bounces, you'd have to modulate not only the amplitude but also the frequency.  This would become problematic because a continuously modulated frequency would lead to asymmetric bumps like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20abs(sin(x%5E2))%20from%200%20to%20sqrt(pi)):

[image]

You could modulate the period and amplitude in a piecewise fashion so that they change for each bounce, but at that point your solution has become more complicated than the correct one.

Comment: The point about the frequency changing for an actual bouncing ball is probably even more important than the point about the shape. Both are good points.

Answer (score 11):

*Looks* are deceiving. But to really answer it really depends on the *intended purpose* of your modeling.

If for example the purpose is for simulation in the cinema, your choice of a rectified sine wave might be 'real' enough. The audience believes it to be real, and everybody is happy.

But if you wanted a flight crew to reach Mars, you better stick with Newton and the real physics equations. Any other approximation could be deadly.